# i can't make my discord bot replies in one channel

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

i'm trying to make my bot

Only replies to command in just one channel.

And if  someone uses the command in other channel,

bot replies 'you should use that command in #here'.

python 3.6.8

discord module : 0.16.12

So i coded like this,

```
if message.channel.id == "(the channel id)":
        if message.content == "sixbomb":
            await client.send_message(message.channel, random.sample(sixbomb,6))
else:
        text_channel = client.get_channel('the channel id')
        msg = '{0.author.mention}님! 그건 {1.mention}에서 써주세요!'.format(message,text_channel)
        await client.delete_message(message)
        await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)
```

but it doesn't work..

bot is just repeating 'msg'... T^T

- it repeats in the correct channel, too.

ex)

[1,2,3,4,5,6]

'~~~님! 그건 {}에서 써주세요!'

'~~~님! 그건 {}에서 써주세요!'

'~~~님! 그건 {}에서 써주세요!'

'~~~님! 그건 {}에서 써주세요!'

'~~~님! 그건 {}에서 써주세요!'

how should I fix it?

Comment: I solved it.. wrong order ㅇㅅㅇ 'if msg.content=="~~" ' should be the first one and the channel.id is under the content=="~~" i think im really idiot one

Comment: '''
    if message.content == "sixbombs":
        if message.channel.id == "(channel id)":
            await client.send_message(message.channel, random.sample(sixbomb,6))
        else:
            Text_channel = coient.get_channel('the channel id')
            msg='{0.author.mention}님! 그건 {1.mention}에서 써주세요!'.format(message,text_channel)
            await client.delete_message(message)
            await client.send_message(message.channel,msg)
'''

It might work.
I recognized my stolidity